# How to generate an array of arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So given:

```
var person = {name: "", address: "", phonenumber: ""}
```

I want to create a loop to receive user input (until they decide they don't want to input anymore information and input nothing or click cancel). I'd also like to use the person object as a prototype.

So I guess an object just to store the name/address/phone number of an arbitrary number of people. My logic for this would be to dynamically add an entire array to an object for every iteration of my loop. My code looks something like this:

```
var person = {name: "", address: "", phonenumber: ""}
var customer = []; //used to store each person


var input = "x";

//loop prompting user to input name/address/phone number
for(var i = 0; input != ""; i++){
  var input = prompt("Input separated by commas"); 
  //example input: mike, main, 123456789

  var results = input.split(", "); //create an array from the input

  //move input into the person array. 
  //person to look like {name = "mike", address = "main", phone = "123456789"}
  person.name = results.shift();
  person.address = results.shift();
  person.phone = results;


  customer[i] = person;//store the person array into the customer array.
}
```

I've been trying to dynamically generate something like this:

```
customer = 
[{name, address, phone}, 
{name, address, phone}, 
{name, address, phone}]
```

and then be able to access it and print it. i've been trying to access it with

```
console.log(customer[0].phone);
```

unfortunately im getting an error.

sorry for my error, console.log prints nothing so it seems like there's nothing stored in customer[0].phone.

i can't get access to any of the data that i've prompted the user for and saved in variables. when i use the alert function all i get is a blank box. whenever i try to print customer i get the message [object Object]or something along those lines

Comment: and, pray tell, what is this "error"?

Comment: What about `console.log(customer)`? Also, you can just use `customer.push(person)`, this way feels more "consistent", without worrying about the index.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce what you want, but it also doesn't generate an error, like you claimed: http://jsfiddle.net/anebvn17/ . Please explain what the real problem is with your code. What is your actual question? You are already seem to know how to add elements to an array.

Comment: See if this helps: http://jsbin.com/tozij/1/edit

Comment: First if you click on the cancel button It will show error because var input = prompt("Input separated by commas"); will set input to null, and then you use input.split() will cause error. And If you click Ok button, I think that you should check the length of customer by alert(customer.length); or using F12 and watch inside the customer variable

Comment: @FelixKling my code does not output anything. Using the console.log function nothing is printed. It seems like the data is not even there?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var customer = [];//create array
  var person = {};// create object
  var input = prompt("...");//your prompt
  var results = input.split(", "); //create an array from the input
  person.name = results[0];//add result with 0 index
  person.address = results[1];//add result with 1 index
  person.phone = results[2];//add result with index 2
  customer[0] = person;//add the person object to the array.
```

The above code should do as you wish. I'm having a hard time seeing why you would iterate a prompt to the same user?? So try this first then go on.

http://jsfiddle.net/zkc2swmp/1/

Don't go irratating your users with prompt boxes, use a form. Also don't iterate something like that, and your condition in the for loop basically creates an infinite loop which is also bad

My code could be a lot better, such as if conditions, and exactly how to use this with a form. Though frankly it seems as though you are far from that. So I've started you off, try it and see if you can implement this the way you want, then comment with suggestions for helping you do something else.

Comment: I'm not making this webpage for anyone. I'm just learning how to do JS so I've just been using scratchpad. And I guess you could say it's almost like a database. Input customer information and then be able to access an element at will. So I iterate the prompt to the same user because you are inputting each customers data! (Think of a store asking for your information)

Comment: Iterating with prompt is still a bad idea. Like others have said if we click cancel it's undefined. If we write hello, well we don't have an multiple arrays. So your code will consistently fail. Your best bet is to use a dummy form. Each time you click `submit` add's that info. Though use some conditional statements to check against the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, every time you are assigning person to customer i.e.
   customer[i] = person;
   all other objects are getting modified as your breaking point is input== "" so all objects are modified with null values.
2. in start you are defining property as "phonenumber" and in the end u r putting value in "phone".

correct code shud be :

```
var customer = []; //used to store each person
var input = "x";

//loop prompting user to input name/address/phone number
for(var i = 0; input != ""; i++){
    var input = prompt("Input separated by commas"); 
    //example input: mike, main, 123456789

    var results = input.split(", "); //create an array from the input
    var person = {};
    person.name = results.shift();
    person.address = results.shift();
    person.phone = results;
    customer[i] = person;//store the person array into the customer array.
}
```

Comment: I still wouldn't have the condition to be checking against `!= ""` because then it still works if it's `"   "` so if the OP were to iterate this, dear lord I hope he doesn't, well I'd use regex to clear all whitespace then check against that. As well as in the loop check if the array length is the amount needed for the OP.

Comment: i edited the code as it was not printing the values, as earlier all values were getting null due to the last input.

Comment: @EasyBB oh. i'm not too worried about bad inputs. it's a practice program so i dont have to user proof it so much